# How to pass array of Json as a parameter to Dataflow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am getting the output of lookup activity as below.

"value": [
{
"PO_id": "XXX",
"SO_number": "YYYY"
},
{
"PO_id": "AAA",
"SO_number": "BBBB"
}
]

I want to pass this lookup activity output as a paremter to dataflow
and convert them into the tabular format

PO_id,SO_number
"XXX","YYYY"
"AAA","BBBB"

There is no Json[] type in dataflow parameter. I tried with string[] parameter, but getting error

'Array elements must be all of same type'. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the Json array as a string to dataflow parameter and then in dataflow use parse transformation to convert them into rows and column.

- Create a dataflow parameter of type string.

[image]

- In pipeline, instead of passing the value for dataflow parameter as `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` , you can pass the value as `@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value)`.
- In Derived column transformation, add the new column `new_col` and define the expression for the column as
  `split(replace(replace(replace($parameter1, '[', ''),']',''),'},','}},'),'},')`

[image]

[image]

- Then add a flatten transformation and unroll by the column `new_col`.
- Then add the parse transformation. Choose Json as format in parse settings. And then choose `single document` in Json settings as a document form. In column settings give the below expression

```
column: new_col
expression:new_col
Output column type:(name as string,dept as string)
```

[Replace name as string,dept as string with required columns and their type]

[image: gif1]

By this way, you can pass the Json array in the dataflow and parse them as rows and column data.